# how to fetch most counted string value from core data

Tags: ios, objective-c, database, core-data, fetch

say I store brand name in "brand" attribute. How do I fetch them in counted order?

for example, if I have 5 Apple,3 Google,1 HP, it should return something like this:

Apple

Google

HP

Comment: Is `Brand` your entity and `name` the attribute for the brand name?

Comment: Brand is my attribute. Entity name is Transaction

Comment: Do you mean it should return 9 records i.e. 5 apple records, followed by 3 google records ecc... or just three records Apple,Google,HP ?

Comment: Just three records in Apple, Google, Hp order since Apple has higher counts in database

Answer (score 0):

Fetch your transactions and then

```
NSArray *unique =  
   [fetchedObjects valueForKeyPath:@"@uniqueUnionOfObjects.brand"]];

NSMutableArray *countsArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:unique.count];
for (NSString *brand in unique) { 
   NSArray *filtered = [fetchedObjects filteredArrayUsingPredicate:
     [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"brand = %@", brand]];
   [countsArray addObject:@{@"brand":brand, @"count":@(filtered.count)}];
}

NSArray *result = [countsArray sortedArrayUsingSortDescriptors:
   @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"count" ascending:NO]]]
```